# /var/log/mail.log getting huge

Tags: 14.04, server, log

I have an issue with Ubuntu 14.04 server.

The issue is that the `/var/log/mail.log` is getting huge and its saturating the server.

My question is: is there a way to do some automatic log rotating so I can limit the log size to some reasonable size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default application to do that is [logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/logrotate.8.html). The config file has some examples on how to rotate. But something like this:

```
/var/log/mail.log
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        reload mail.log >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

for a 7 day rotation.

But! Do have a look at your mail.log and see if what is put in there is not an ERROR or someone abusing your system as a relay to send out spam.

Comment: Yes you where right , we had nonworking smtp server that caused the log to accumulate

Comment: Thanks for the log rotation script , question how should i implement it , should I use cron ? if yes can you elaborate with me example  ,Thanks

Comment: logrotate uses its own daemon.

Comment: logrotate usually installs its own cron file in `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`, so runs daily by default.

Comment: @user1289947 As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**